# $C^1$ eigenvectors of a Jacobian Matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jacobian

Let $F: \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a $C^2$ function given by
$F(u,v)=(F_1(u,v),F_2(u,v))$. 
   Assume that the Jacobian matrix
$$ DF(u,v)=\begin{pmatrix}
  \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u}(u,v) & \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial v}(u,v) \\ 
  \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial u}(u,v) & \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial v}(u,v)
\end{pmatrix}$$
has two real and distinct eigenvalues $\lambda(u,v)<\mu(u,v)$. I have seen in the literature that a right eigenvector of $DF(u,v)$ associtated to $\lambda$ ( let's say $r_{\lambda}(u,v)$  ) may be chosen so $r_{\lambda}$ vary smoothly with $(u,v)$ (at least locally), but I don't realize how this can be proved. Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: The details may be a bit messier, but this should follow from two applications of the Implicit Function Theorem: one to show the Eigenvalues depend smoothly on the input and then one to show the Eigenvector depends smoothly on the Eigenvalue.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I will try to see the problem using this approach.

Comment: @Thorgott that was my first instinct as well, but I only managed to show that the eigenvalues vary smoothly with $(u,v)$, but not the eigenvectors. Because a naive application of the implicit function theorem isn't possible, we have the smooth function $\Bbb{R} \times \Bbb{R} \times (\Bbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}) \to \Bbb{R}^2$ given as $(u,v, r) \mapsto [DF_{(u,v)} - \lambda(u,v)I](r)$. If we differentiate with respect to $r$, we get the linear map $DF_{(u,v)} - \lambda(u,v)I$, which is not invertible precisely because the $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue. So, the hypotheses of the IFT aren't satisfied.

Comment: You are right. What I suggested is a bit silly: the IFT is concerned with uniquely solvable equations, but Eigenvectors aren't unique, so this is more akin to finding some sort of choice function. I think this can be fixed by picking an Eigenvector canonically, namely one of unit length (there are two of these at any point, but, by working locally, we can force a unique such choice by picking a direction) and this will depend smoothly on the point. I can't make this precise without going through $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^1$ though, so there ought to be a more straightforward solution.

Comment: Actually, I don't think anything should stop us from doing this "explicitly". Fix a small neighborhood in which one coordinate of the matrix doesn't vanish, then we can use the same Gauss elimination to bring these matrices into RREF smoothly. We then get a single linear equation in two variables, for which we can pick a canonical smooth solution easily (for $ax+by=0$, pick $x=-b,y=a$).